# Php XDebug, one page listen to incoming requests from another page

Tags: php, xdebug

I'm using Eclipse with XDebug trying to debug some php files(I'm really new to php so I'm also looking for best way to debug php). So what I'm trying to do is:

- from page `a.html` I'm sending some info through ajax(type:"POST",url: "b.php") to a second `b.php` page where I do sth with that data and echo it back to be showed on ajax `success` on first page `a.html`.
- what I want is to be able to debug(with breakpoints and maybe some console where I can insert instructions like dev tools from chrome) `b.php` page when ajax request has been sent from `a.html`(I want to see how sent data arrive here)

Is there a way to do that?Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve by inserting `xdebug.remote_autostart = on` in php.ini from apache(not from php) folder.